# Erro ao iniciar PowerShell no Windows Server 2008 R2. Como resolver?

Tags: sql, windows, servidor, powershell, sql-server-2014

Tenho instalado o SQL Server 2014. Ao iniciar o PowerShell no Windows Server 2008 R2 e faço o comando "sqlps" para testar, acontece esse erro que mostra na imagem abaixo...

OBS: Em um outro computador, com windows 7 e mesma versão SQL Server 2014, funciona normalmente.

Como resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro em texto:

"Import-Module : Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell
\Modules\SQLPS\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll because of the following error: Unable to load one or more
of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Loader Exceptions:
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=898
45dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=898
45dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=898
45dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=898
45dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:14
+ import-module <<<<  SQLPS  -DisableNameChecking
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Import-Module], PSSnapInException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSnapInLoadFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand"

Comment: tente no Windows Server 2012

Comment: Evite o uso de imagens pra representar erros ou códigos, leitores, crawlers e buscadores (inclusive do proprio SOpt). Não cole imagens de códigos e de erros, use Ctrl+C pra copiar os textos reais, isto facilita a busca.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa instalar o [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Shared Management Objects](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978) antes de utilizar `Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser`.

Este é o item que você deve baixar e instalar, de acordo com a versão do seu ambiente operacional:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>